# iOS code signing key 'Apple Development: David (V26CS7XT)' not found in keychain. I am trying to create IPA in visual studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

iOS code signing key 'Apple Development: David  (V26CS7XT)' not found in keychain. I am trying to create IPA in visual studio(xamarin forms). I have a MacBook that I installed xcode and visual studio and I am connected to Macbook on visual studio (window).

Please assist. Its for testflight

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/no-codesigning-keys . this might help

Comment: Hello! You need to be sure that you have all you keys in keychain. Please check this instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows